# Django 2.7 Rest API Validation Request

Tags: django, python-2.7, rest, api, validation

I use Django 2.7 to build Rest API application, and having problem to validate/clean the request data from client for get detail transaction (Not Save/update). for example the request data **trx_no** cannot less than 5 char length. where's the validation class i should create? should I validate on Model.py or using forms, or in serializer?
Here's my **models.py:**

```
class mst_trx(models.Model):
    trx_no = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True)
```

Here's my **views.py:**

```
class views_index(APIView):

def post(self,request):
    action = request.POST['action']

    if action == 'detail' :
        resp = detail.as_view()(request)


class detail(APIView):
    def dispatch(self,request): 

    ##I want to validate first before get data
    try:
        detail = mst_trx.objects.select_related().get(pk=request.POST['trx_no'])
    except mst_trx.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Transaction does not exist")
    else:
        serializer = TrxDetailSerializer(detail)
        return serializer.data
```

And Here's my **serializer.py :**

```
class TrxDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = mst_trx
        fields = ('trx_no')
```

Answer (score 1):

Validation logic should be in forms.py file

for e.g.

```
def clean_columnname(self):
    columnname = self.cleaned_data['columnname']
    if len(columnname) < 1:
        raise ValidationError('Please add some content  ...')
    elif len(columnname) > 500000:
        raise ValidationError('Too many characters ...')
    return columnname
```

Comment: @dennysaputra You just need to call isValid() for your form and `clean_fieldname` will be called.

`form = YourForm(request.POST)
 form.is_valid()`
For more details you can refer [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/)